# Call the text box with unique name in php $_POST

Tags: php, loops, post, get, inputbox

I'm really new for php, I'm not sure how to call each of the input in my Php post, because I'm using unique name for the input text, I tried this 
$serial= $_POST['serial'][$n]; but it doesn't work. Anyone can help me..?  $n is actually something to differentiate my column by model in database. And I declared it on top of my page

```
     <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("pdnoutput");

    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");
    $date=date('Y-m-d');
    $datee= $_POST['date'];
    $model= $_GET['model'];
    $lot= $_GET['lot'];

    $num = 1;
    $res = mysql_query("select * from excelsno where lot = '$lot'")or die (mysql_error());

     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
     { 
     $n1=$num++;
     $lotsize = $row['lotsize'];
     $form="QAFG01";
     $dat=date("ymd");
     $idd= "{$dat}{$row['model']}{$row['dest']}{$form}{$row['lot']}";
     $n = "{$row['model']}{$row['dest']}";
     $nom = $row['lot'];
     $nam1 = $row['lotsize'];
     $nam2 =  "{$row['startsno1']}{$row['startsno2']}";
     $nam3 =  "{$row['endsno1']}{$row['endsno2']}";
     $nam4 =  $row['pdate'];
      ?>

    <?php 
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("smtform1"); 
    $num = 1;
    $res = mysql_query("select * from speciform where freq = '$lot' AND dstamp >= CURDATE() and nn < 50 ORDER BY id ASC  ")or die (mysql_error());
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
     {  
     ?>
       <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row['freq'];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['dstamp'];?></td>
          <td><input id ="MI" type="text" name="n1" value="<?php echo $num++; ?>" readonly= "readonly" style="width: 22px;"/></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="serial<?php echo $n; ?> " value="<? echo $row['nam5']; ?>"/></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="appereance<?php echo $n; ?>" value="<? **strong text**

    echo

     $row['nam6']; ?>" style="width: 45px;"/>
        </td>
         <td>
          <input type="text" name="sound<?php echo $n; ?>" value="<? echo $row['nam7']; ?>" style="width: 45px;"  />
        </td>
          <td><input type="text" name="wi_test<?php echo $n; ?>" value="<? echo  $row['nam8']; ?>" style="width: 45px;" />
        </td>
          <td><input type="text" name="remark<?php echo $n; ?>" value="<? echo $row['nam9']; ?>"/></td>
        </tr>
     <? } ?>
```

This my PHP;_

```
    for($i=1;$i<=$number;$i++)
    {
    $idd= "{$dat}{$row['model']}{$row['dest']}{$form}{$row['lot']}";
         $n1=$_POST['n1'];
         $lotsize=$_POST['lotsize'];
         $n = $_POST['n'];
         $nom =$_POST['nom'];
         $nam1 =$_POST['nam1'];
         $serial[$i]= $_POST['serial'][$n];

        //get the result of the textbox



         $inspector= $_POST['inspector'];

        echo $serial[$i]; 

        $query = mysql_query("update speciform set nam5='$serial[i]',nam10='$inspector' where freq = '$lot' and nn < 50") or die( mysql_error());
    }
```

Comment: What is $n ? You have not declared it anywhere.

Comment: `name="serial<?php echo $n; ?> "` Suppose `$n` is set and an integer, you'd access them via `$_POST['serial1']`, `$_POST['serial2']` etc., depending on `$n`. Fyi, you have a trailing space in that name `name="serial<?php echo $n; ?> "`

Comment: Sorry I don't get u..what's the solution maybe? @kerbholz

Comment: actually I declared $n on top of my page, all $n is $n = "{$row['model']}{$row['dest']}"; from another query. I can send the data to database well, but now the problem is I don't know how to call It back for Update @shreyasdharav

Comment: If you declared `$n` it would be nice to post that in your code, all _we_ see is you didn't declare it. Paste that in your code, please. Also, `$serial[i]` is invalid, there is no `i` in your code, that should be `$serial[$i]`.

Comment: `name="serial<?php echo $n; ?> "` There's a trailing space, remove that

Comment: I made the correction as u said but nothing change @kerbholz

Comment: Because `$_POST['serial'][$n]` doesn't exist. You gave it a name, view the source code of that page and see what name it has. Since we don't know what `$n` is, there's not much we can do. It could be `$_POST['serial1']` or `$_POST['serialWhAtEvEr']`.

Comment: @kerbholz I edited my question , I've included my $n for u

Comment: Change `$serial[i]= $_POST['serial'][$n];` to `$serial[$i]= $_POST["serial{$row['model']}{$row['dest']}"];` and you should be good to go.

Comment: nothing happen I still can't  echo $serial[i];  its still blank @kerbholz any other reason/way?

Comment: Because there is no `i`, it's `$i`!!!

Comment: Why don't you try `name="serial<?php echo $row['id']; ?> "` ?

Comment: Ya already change it in my local @kerbholz

Comment: then how to call it back? in when POST @shreyasdharav